# Extrapolate 95% CI for unit decrease and for percentage decrease from lmer outputs

Tags: r, mean, confidence-interval, effects, emmeans

I am testing the association between percentage of impervious surface areas (ISA) and number of eggs per breeding event. This is my model structure:

```
fit=lmer(CS~ISA+Mass_Fem*LayDate+Year+(1|Site),data=DataGT_noNA)
```

Where CS is clutch size, ISA is imperviousness (as %), mass female is the female body mass in grams, Lay date is an ordinal number, and Year is a 5-levels factor. The random effect "Site" has 8 levels.

After obtaining the estimates of loss by a certain %ISA using ggplot and ggeffects as follows:

```
effects_ISA <- effects::effect(term= "ISA", mod= fit, xlevels=list(ISA=c(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70)))
```

I made a dataframe containing all these values as follows

x_ISA <- as.data.frame(effects_ISA)
and obtained this table as a result:

[image]

I would like to obtain the unit decrease (and respective confidence intervals) in terms of number of eggs (including 95% CI) by a given percentage of ISA. See example below:

An increase of 30% of ISA, corresponds to a 0.54 (CI95??) loss in number of eggs. I would like to get the same info as a percentage (% loss and % CI95%)

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my issue by using the R package [marginaleffects](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/):

Specifically, I wrote this code:

```r
avg_comparisons(mymodel, variables = list(ISA = 30))
```

and got these results:

```r
 Term Contrast Estimate Std. Error     z Pr(>|z|) 2.5 %  97.5 %
  ISA      +30   -0.537      0.252 -2.13    0.033 -1.03 -0.0432
```